# Trouble receiving Nodejs response from a Post request (not using express)

Tags: node.js, http, post, xmlhttprequest

My server receives my post request just fine, but I get no response from the server (and nothing through my web inspector either). I've set up my headers for cross origin and everything. Here is my nodejs server code. Code in question is at the bottom.

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {

if(request.url === '/action'){
    //console.log("momma I made it");
    let body = '';
    request.on('data', chunk => {
        body += chunk.toString();
    });
    request.on('end', () => {
        var log = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(parse(body)));
        console.log(log);
        if(log.accT == 'Admin') {
            if(log.account == 'nUser'){
                console.log("this is an new user");
                randnum = random();
                var sql = "INSERT INTO Admin (adminName, adminEmail, adminPassword, adminID) VALUES ('" +log.username+ "', '" +log.email+ "', '" +log.password+ "', '" +randnum+ "')"
                con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    response.end('new user created, changed response remotely')
                });
            }
            if(log.account == 'eUser'){
                console.log("this is an existing user");

                var sql = "SELECT adminName,adminPassword FROM Admin WHERE adminName = '"+log.username+"'";
                con.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    //var pass = parse(result);
                    if(result.length != 0 && result[0].adminPassword === log.password) response.end('youre in big guy')
                    else response.end('wrong username or password');
                });
            }
        }
        if(log.accT == 'Sponsor') {
            if(log.account == 'nUser'){
                console.log("this is an new user");
                randnum = random();
                var sql = "INSERT INTO Sponsor (adminEmail,sponsorEmail, sponsorName, sponsorPassword, sponsorID) VALUES ('" +log.authEmail+ "','" +log.email+ "', '" +log.username+ "', '" +log.password+ "', '" +randnum+ "')"
                con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    response.end('new user created, changed response remotely')
                });
            }
            if(log.account == 'eUser'){
                console.log("this is an existing user");

                var sql = "SELECT sponsorName,sponsorPassword FROM Sponsor WHERE sponsorName = '"+log.username+"'";
                con.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    //var pass = parse(result);
                    if(result.length != 0 && result[0].sponsorPassword === log.password) response.end('youre in big guy')
                    else response.end('wrong username or password');
                });
            }
        }
        if(log.accT == 'Driver') {
            if(log.account == 'nUser'){
                console.log("this is an new user");
                randnum = random();
                var sql = "INSERT INTO Driver (sponsorEmail, driverName, driverEmail, driverPassword, driverID) VALUES ('" +log.authEmail+ "','" +log.username+ "','" +log.email+ "', '" +log.password+ "', '" +randnum+ "')"
                con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    response.end('new user created, changed response remotely')
                });
            }
            if(log.account == 'eUser'){
                console.log("this is an existing user");

                var sql = "SELECT driverName,driverPassword FROM Driver WHERE driverName = '"+log.username+"'";
                con.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    //var pass = parse(result);
                    if(result.length != 0 && result[0].driverPassword === log.password) response.end('youre in big guy')
                    else response.end('wrong username or password buckaroo');
                });
            }
        }
        if(log.action == 'update'){

            //response.write('hello');
        }
        //response.end('ok');
    });
    //response.writeHead(200)
    //fs.createReadStream('server2.html').pipe(response)  // do NOT use fs's sync methods ANYWHERE on production (e.g readFileSync) 
}
if(request.url === '/myaction'){
    response.writeHead(200)
    fs.createReadStream('SignUp.html').pipe(response)  // do NOT use fs's sync methods ANYWHERE on production (e.g readFileSync)  
}
if(request.url === '/myaction2'){
    response.writeHead(200)
    fs.createReadStream('SignIn.html').pipe(response)  // do NOT use fs's sync methods ANYWHERE on production (e.g readFileSync)  
}
if(request.url === '/?action=update'){
    //response.write('hello Isaac');
}
if (request.method == 'POST') {
    console.log("POST");
    var body = '';
    request.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data;
        console.log("Partial body: " + body);
    });
    request.on('end', function () {
        console.log("Body: " + body);
    });
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.end('post received'); 
}
```

and here is my html receiving code

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "url not posted because I have no security", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
};
xhttp.send('action=update');
```

And my server receives the message just fine. Any help is greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: Try to change on the server side to `response.setHeader`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem an earlier stage, when I tried to send a response to HTML just a plain text. it's doesn't send a response to HTML. so what I did that is i have stored value in variable and given  `response.end(variable_name);` and that was worked fine...

please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Ok I figured it out. I should have used double quotes in my response.end. Weirdly enough all the examples online used single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Nodejs http doesn't have header method. You have to use setHeader method `response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');`

Comment: Yeah, not sure how I deleted that but I had setHeader before. Just changed it to this but still nothing. Changed my original post

Comment: Posted full http.createServer

Comment: Thanks Sanchonn for all the help I just needed double quotes in this statement. response.end('post received');